# Determining if a graph has a cycle without using DFS

Tags: algorithm, graph, cycle, depth-first-search

I came around one of those questions in my exams:

> Topologocial sorting using [Kahn's
>   Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Algorithms)
>   requires the graph to be DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph). How can we
>   determine if a graph contains no cycles without using DFS/BFS first?

I am trying to answer that for too long now and I am baffled. Can anyone point out to me an algorithm that determines that a graph has no cycles that **DOESN'T** use DFS or should I go rampaging to my instructor?

Comment: Kahn's algorithm does detect cycles too.

Comment: If at some point during kahn's algorithm has no source to choose, there is a cycle (obviously), pretty sure it holds for the oposite direction as well (if there is a cycle, at some point you will have no source), but will have to think about a proof to this claim.

Comment: @amit If there is a cycle, there's no way Kahn's algorithm can at any point choose any of the nodes in it as a source.

Comment: @biziclop Yea, this is obviously, the other side is a bit trickier to prove, confused the directions. (But only a bit trickier...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If and only if, at some point during kahn's algorithm has no source to choose (and the remaining graph is still none empty), there is a cycle

**Proof:**

Direction1 `<--`:

If there is a cycle, let it be `v1->v2->v3->vk->v1`.

At each step of the algorithm, none of `v1,v2,...,vk` is a source - proving it by induction by showing you never remove any of these edges

Direction2 `-->`:

If at some point during kahn's algorithm has no source to choose, though the algorithm is not finished yet, then every node (at the reminder graph) has an incoming edge.

Assume there is no cycle, and let `v1->v2->..->vk` be the longest simple path in the reminder graph.

But, `v1` has an incoming edge, so there is some node `v0` such that `v0->v1->...->vk` is also a path, and since we assumed there are no cycles, it is also simple path. 

Contradiction to maximality of `v1->..->vk`